# Удалить тег, основываясь на его содержимом

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть текст:

```
<hr class="h1"><sftxt>Hello World!</sftxt><hr class="h1">
```

Так же есть текст:

```
<hr class="h1"><bxtwt>Hello World!</bxtwt><hr class="h1">
```

Как можно удалить тэг `<hr class="h1">` из текста приведенного выше? Причем только если рядом с этим тэгом идет тэг `<sftxt>` или `</bxtwt>` или `<bxtwt>` или `</sftxt>`

ибо если текст имеет другой формат, допустим

```
<hr class="h1"><div class="text">qwerty</div>123456<br><hr class="h1">
```

то тогда в этом случае `<hr class="h1">` мы не трогаем

Answer (score 0):

я бы советовал использовать класс [simple_dom_html_parser php](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/), сделать селектор типа

```
foreach($html->find('hr.h1') as $elem) {
   // здесь ищем в $elem теги из задачи
   // ...
   // при необходимости удаляем
   // ...
}//foreach($html->find('hr.h1') as $elem)
```

Answer (score 0):

Если интересует решение на чистых регулярках, то вот один из вариантов:

```
$string = '
    <hr class="h1"><sftxt>Hello World!</sftxt><hr class="h1">
    <hr class="h1"><bxtwt>Hello World!</bxtwt><hr class="h1">
    <hr class="h1"><div class="text">qwerty</div>123456<br><hr class="h1">
';

$pattern = '~
    (?:<hr[^>]*>(?=(?:<sftxt>|<bxtwt>))|
    (?<=(?:</sftxt>|</bxtwt>))<hr[^>]*>)
~x';

echo preg_replace($pattern, '', $string);
/* Результат:
<sftxt>Hello World!</sftxt>
<bxtwt>Hello World!</bxtwt>
<hr class="h1"><div class="text">qwerty</div>123456<br><hr class="h1">
*/
```

Answer (score -1):

Вот решение в лоб:

```
$text = '<hr class="h1"><sftxt>Hello World!</sftxt><hr class="h1">';
$text = preg_replace('/<hr class=\"h1\">\$*(?=<sftxt>|<bxtwt>|<\/sftxt>|<\/bxtwt>)/', '', $text);
echo preg_replace('/(?<=<sftxt>|<bxtwt>|<\/sftxt>|<\/bxtwt>)\$*<hr class=\"h1\">/', '', $text);
```